# Update Modified field in Office 365

Tags: office-365, updatelistitems

Is there any way to update the `Modified` field in Office 365? I have checked both CSOM and Batch update methods. But it's failed. Could anybody help me to update this field.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint CSOM API does not support system update ([SystemUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate(v=office.15).aspx) counterpart from SSOM API)  but you could manipulate system fields like `Modified By` and `Modified` fields directly as demonstrated below.

> Prerequisites:  [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{
    //get List Item
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    //Retrieve User
    var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(accountName);
    ctx.Load(user);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    //Update system fields
    item["Modified"] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
    item["Created"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    item["Editor"] = user.Id;
    item["Author"] = user.Id;
    item.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
}
```

Follow [System update for SharePoint list items using App model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/08/26/system-update-for-sharepoint-list-items-using-app-model.aspx) article for a more details